# Sale basura cuando uso un bucle while en C++ con iteradores

Tags: c++, iteradores

Quiero insertar un número en la segunda posición usando un iterador, luego lo presento por pantalla, pero me sale basura.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(4);
    for(int i=0; i<v.size();i++)v[i]=i+1;

    vector<int> ve(4);
    for(int i=0; i<ve.size();i++)ve[i]=i+1;

    vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin();
    b++;
    v.insert(b,2);

    while(b!=v.end())
    {
         cout << *b << ", ";
         b++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Esto sale cuando lo ejecuto:

```
5270960, 3, 4, 647170883, 134225313, 1, 2, 3, 4, 546507589, 134225313, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4,
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es muy sencillo de solucionar:

```
vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin( );
b++;
v.insert( b, 2 );

while( b != v.end( ) ) {
...
```

Según es estándar:

> #### std::vector::insert
>
> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

Lo cual, en una traducción libre, viene a decir que si el nuevo tamaño `size( )` es **mayor** que el anterior tamaño `capacity( )`, el vector puede ser *realojado* en memoria, lo cual conlleva la **invalidación** de todos los iteradores.

En otras palabras, si para *hacer sitio* para nuevos elementos es necesario **redimensionar** el bloque de memoria utilizado por el `vector< >`, los iteradores dejarán de *apuntar* al lugar correcto, y posteriores usos de los mismos darán resultados *indefinidos*.

En tu caso, para solucionar el problema, basta con añadir `b = v.begin( )` justo despues de `v.insert( )`:

```
v.insert( b, 2 );
b = v.begin( );
```

Otra posible solución es aumentar el actual `capacity( )` **antes** de añadir, para lo cual se usa `reserve( )`:

```
v.reserve( v.size( ) + 1 );
vector< int >::iterator b = v.begin( );

b++;
v.insert( b, 2 );

while( b != v.end( ) ) {
```

...